# Elastic Beantstalked on deployment Approximate age of oldest message spikes

Tags: amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-sqs

I'm noticing recurring behaviour when we deploy a new version of our Worker Environment on AWS Elastic Beanstalk.
Each time we deploy we see the Approximate Age Of Oldest Message on the queue spike to 1800s.
Our EB environment has a Visibility timeout of 1800s and a Inactivity timeout of 1799s.

My current thinking is that when a deployment starts, the jobs currently in flight aren't correctly finished before the server is replaced. They are then stuck in limbo until the Visibility/Inactivity timeout expires and the job returns to the queue for processing (and gets done in a timely manner then).

Deployment is set to rolling with health checks, there's 3 instances running and I've tried batch sizes of 100% and 50% to no avail.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.